# Is there a difference between ΚΘ and ΧΘ?

Tags: greek, phonology, consonants, aspiration

According to what I'd previously learned, aspirated stop clusters in Ancient Greek only had a single aspiration, at the end of the whole cluster. The reason for writing *χθών* "earth", *φθόγγος* "sound" instead of **κθών*, **πθόγγος* was convention more than anything else.

However, I'm now realizing that prefixes don't always follow this convention: *ἔκθυμος* "spirited", not **ἔχθυμος*.

Was this just a spelling convention? Or was there actually a difference in pronunciation between *κθ* and *χθ*?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is Allen, *Vox Graeca* (15):

[image]

Allen and Sturtevant (*Pronunciation of Greek and Latin*) both argue, based on the rarity of misspellings of the type *κθών, that the first consonant in such clusters really was aspirated, i.e. this was not just a spelling convention.